# IndexOutOfBound printing array from the end

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to read an Array from the last element to the first one and change them in some cases. But i don't know why i am getting index out of bounds exception .

```
public class Test
{
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );

    private int dimension;

    private int[] a;

    public int getDimension() {
        return dimension;
    }

    public void setDimension(int dimension) {
        this.dimension = dimension;
    }

    public Test(int dimension) {
        System.out.println("Add elements");
        setDimension(dimension);
        this.a = new int[this.dimension];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.dimension; i++)
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    public void calc() {
        int aux = 0;
        for(int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            if(a[i] > a[i-1]) {
                aux = a[i-1];
                a[i-1] = a[i];
                a[i] = aux;
            }
        for(int i = 0; i < getDimension(); i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test p = new Test(5);
        p.calc();
    }
}
```

Comment: When encountering an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, try to print the indexes you use. You will eventually see why you got it in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    if(a[i]>a[i-1]){
```

when `i=0` then you are pointing to `a[-1]`.

Change it to `for(int i = a.length-1; i > 0; i--)` and it should work unless there is another problem